# how to use 'string' variable as 'objectForkey' in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to use string as `objectForkey`. my code line is this.

And I want to use "strend" as a `objectForkey` but it didn't work.

Code is:

```
NSString *strend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[detwec.arrdetails objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"EndDate"]];

NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"strend" ]];
```

Comment: !? what doesnt work: whats the value of strend and whats the error you get and whats _currentItemValue :)

Comment: what's _currentItemValue ? a dictionary?

Comment: Does _currentItemValue respond to objectForKey? I mean, is it a NSDictionary or something like this? Are you sure that it contains an object for your key?

Comment: use `[_currentItemValue objectForKey:strend]`

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this line

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"strend" ]];
```

by this

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_currentItemValue objectForKey:strend]];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read a value using string as key you can use:

```
NSString *value = ["Your Dictionary" objectForKey:strend];
```

get a check that your NSString *strend shouldn't be "nil" else will not give you any value.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try

```
NSString *strend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[detwec.arrdetails objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"EndDate"];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"strend" ]];
```

or else

```
NSString *dateString = [_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"strend" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString *strend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[detwec.arrdetails objectAtIndex:0]];     NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:strend forKey:@"strend"];
 NSString *dateString = [storeData objectForKey:@"strend"];